# React Native: Disable Xiaomi Game Turbo programatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in some xiaomi devices where I installed my react native apk I get a weird "Game Turbo" modal and a floating tab, is there a way to disable this programatically? Not from device settings but with code...

Also, what is Game Turbo for exactly, I haven't felt any difference?